# Django InMemoryUploadFile content and name manipulation

Tags: python, django, file-upload

Hi I am still new to Django and Python and I have problem understanding the API, so it is totally possible I am missing something obvious.

I receive a file "through" the `FileField` of a `forms.Form` (Django). And thus manage to get an instance of `InMemoryUploadedFile`. This form is not linked to a Model.
Before putting the file in a model and save it (I am using S3BotoStorage), I would like to change the file name and encrypt the file content (really now it's just doing nothing special I am still testing this).

What I do not understand is how to access the file name and data content of the file and overwrite it? or create a modified instance of my `InMemoryUploadedFile`.

I had in mind of using something like this, but obviously it doesn't work.

```
def encrypt(inMemFile, key):
    assert isinstance(inMemFile, InMemoryUploadedFile)
    secret = m2secret.Secret()
    secret.encrypt(inMemFile.read(), key)
    inMemFile.file = File(secret.serialize(), uuid.uuid4().get_hex())
    return inMemFile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a `File` instance to the model field. Something like this should work:

```
obj = form.save(commit=False)
# [...] your encryption stuff [...]
obj.some_file_field = ContentFile(secret.serialize(), uuid.uuid4().get_hex())
obj.save()
form.save_m2m()
```

See also the second example of the section [Handling uploaded files with a model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model) in the Django documentation.
Be aware that larger files are not handled in-memory; they are `TemporaryUploadedFile` instances.